# Solve $ab = 2(a+b)$ using modular arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> I have the following equation which I want to solve where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> \begin{align*}ab &= 2(a+b) \\ \iff ab &= 2a + 2b \\ \iff ab - 2a &= 2b \\ \iff a(b-2) &= 2b \\ \iff a &= \frac{2b}{b-2}\end{align*}

Therefore I must solve for $a,b$ such that all pairs $\displaystyle(a,b) = \bigg(\frac{2b}{b-2},b\bigg)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$

I must now find, using modulo properties, the values of $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ which satisfies the equation.

Clearly $(0,0)$ is a solution, but $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$. We cannot have $b=1$ since then $a<1$ and $b =2$ is a horizontal asymptote.

Notice, however that $ \displaystyle a = \frac{2b}{b-2} = 2 + \frac{4}{b-2}$. Thus for $a$ to be an integer, we require $(b-2)|4$.

Hence we must have that $4 \equiv 0 \mod{(b-2)}$.

Thus we have the following equations:

$b-2 = 1 \implies b = 3 \implies a = 3$

$b-2 = 2 \implies b = 4 \implies a = 4$

$b-2 = 4  \implies b = 6 \implies a = 3$

Thus our solutions are given by $$\{ (6,3), (4,4), (3,6) \} $$

Is the steps and reasoning used correct?

Comment: You only proved that $\displaystyle(a,b) = \bigg(\frac{2b}{b-2},b\bigg), b >2$ is a necessary condition ($\therefore$ is $\implies$, which is not $\iff$). You can't just say 'therefore [it is sufficient]'. You'd either have to substitute that pair in the initial equation or use $\iff$ instead of $\therefore$.

Comment: @user314 - Thank you. I changed it to $\iff$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
$$a =\dfrac{2b}{b-2} = 2 + \dfrac{4}{b-2}$$

That means, for $a$ to be an integer we must have $(b-2) | 4$

So $b-2$ has to be a factor of $4$.

Comment: Thank you! I updated it using your hint. Is the steps and reasoning used correct? Or is there anything that needs to be changed or added?

Comment: Your work looks good to me!